# How install SharePoint Online, what is Procedure and requirement

Tags: sharepoint-online, installation, sharepoint-integration

is this Possible to install SharePoint Online without Install SharePoint Server,  I need SharePoint Online 2013 Installation Steps

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online is cloud-based, no need to install anything in the server, you just need to buy a tenant in office 365, rest all Microsoft will take care - we should not bother about managing the server - we are just buying the software as service here. Here, there is no relation between SharePoint 2013 on-premise and SharePoint Online.

However, if you want to install the SharePoint 2013, refer to the below article for the step by step process:

[Step by step Installation of SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 part 1](https://collab365.community/step-by-step-installation-of-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-server/)

Answer (score 0):

To get SharePoint Online, you can contact Microsoft 365 sales expert from here:

https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-M365SMB-web-contact.html?culture=en-us&country=US

You can see planing and price from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans

Answer (score 0):

If you need sharepoint online, you need to buy a o365 tenant only. O365 is a Saas with exchange, teams, Sharepoint and other products under its suite.

You must first go through the documentation on how to create a tenant and which plan to choose. Depending on the size of your organization, there are different plans available.

There is no requirement to insatll any thing for SharePoint Online. Also please note that SharePoint online will have the latest features available as all the new features are pushed to Online first and then to the Server versions like 2016,2019.